# need help to custom expandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new to android, and I want to implement a ListView like the image below[image: ExpandableListView]. It seems expandableListView may meet my request, but what I want is only `Item 4` has children and can be expanded, 'Item 1' is just an option user can click, and can't be expanded. I read the document of Expandable List View, and it's not clear enough how to implement this. Can anyone gave some suggestion on implementing this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what I want is only Item 4 has children and can be expanded

If Item doesn't have children, it won't be exanded. You can image that like:

```
public class Item {

   private String title;
   private List<Option> children; // if size = 0 won't be expanded
}
```

It's native behaviour of `ExpandableListView` so if any Item doesn't have children, implicitly won't be expanded but you need to set OnClickListener for both groups (Items) and children (Options):

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View row, 
                           int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

   // callback method after click for Options
   return false;
}


public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View row, 
                             int groupPosition, long id) {

   /** if you are using BaseAdapter subclass implementation **/

   adapter.getGroup(groupPosition)).getChildren() == null) {
      // item doesn't have children
   }
   else {
      // has children
   }
```

Generally if you want to get more control over your ListView i pretty recommend you to implement own subclass of ListAdapter in your case you can use [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html).

And an appearance of List is only issue about proper styled layouts for example removing group indicator with

```
android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

### Update:

Issue mentioned by @Roberto Lombardini:

> A little problem with this solution is that the little grey triangle
>   indicating the state of the groupview (expanded or not) will appear
>   even if group has no children. Am i wrong?

If you want to have gray triangle only for Items with children, you need to fix it in your custom adapter in `getGroupView()` method:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   // inflating View etc.

   Item item = items.get(groupPosition);
   if (item != null) {

      // if Item has children
      if (item.getChildren() != null && !item.getChildren().isEmpty()) {

         // set children indicator to VISIBLE
         imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
      }
      // if Item doesn't have children
      else {
         // set children indicator to GONE
         imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A little problem with this solution is that the little grey triangle indicating the state of the groupview (expanded or not) will appear even if group has no children. Am i wrong?

Comment: You need to fix it in getGroupView() method of custom adapter. Main "idea" of custom list adapters is that you have full control over appearance of List - customize layouts due to data.

Comment: Thanks for you guys' help, it's helpful, and I will try this method.:)

Comment: @Sajmon should I just return null in getChildView for group that have no children?

Comment: @Charlesjean no. here can appear sometimes NullPointerEpxection. Dont trying it.

Comment: i think that returning an empty `convertView` can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement some custom Adapter, I think could be the better way to do what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
 lv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
     public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         switch (position) {
             case 0: return true;
             case 2: return true; // returning true wont expand 
             default:
                 return false;// if you return false then only that position will be expanded
             }
         }
     }
);
```

just return false on the which parent position you want to expand and in which you dont want to expand you can return true.